# onImageclicklistener to upload images in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onitemclicklistener

I have two activities. First activity is a layout to upload images inside. The second activity is an adapter and shows a image gallery for the uploads. I want to write a inner class onImageClickListener inside the Adapter to select images for the upload.

```
class OnImageClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    int _position;

    //constructor
    public OnImageClickListener (int position) {
        _position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(_activity, LayoutForThreeActivity.class);
    }
}
```

The clicklistener have to commit the selected image from the gallery on the LayoutForThreeActivity and show it into a imageView. How can i do this?

Here is the code from the LayoutForThreeActivity

```
 image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LayoutForThreeActivity.this, GridViewActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            //startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
        }
    });

    image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2);
        }
    });

    image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE3);
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LayoutForThreeActivity.this, SaveCompositionActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


        //Todo


    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


        //Todo

    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


        //Todo

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    });


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imgUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if i click on an image, nothing happens. What is wrong with the code?

Have you an idea, how i can implement the onImageClickListener form my own Gallery that i wrote?

Comment: you need path for image then it set to imageview.. with position you can't do see below code

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
private ImageView imgUpload;
private Button btnUpload;
private Uri filePath;
private Bitmap bitmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    imgUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgUpload);
    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);


    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    });  

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imgUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }  }
```